# Using Custom ostream Like cout

Tags: c++, stringstream, ostream

How can I use my ostream as if it were cout. My goal is to make it add an item as a string, pushed back to Items, which is an std::vector.

```
class ImGuiPrint
{
    ImGuiPrint( ImGuiPrint && ) = default;
public:
    __PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL std::ostream out;
    template< typename T > friend ImGuiPrint operator<<( ImGuiPrint &out, const T &in );
};

template< typename T > ImGuiPrint operator<<( ImGuiPrint &out, const T &in )
{
    out << in;
    const char *buf = out.out.str( ).c_str(  );
    Items.push_back( Strdup( buf ) );
    return out;
}
```

this aint workin'

Comment: What is "not working"? Explain carefully please. Also what is `__PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL`? Compiler specific?

Comment: It says that there are too many arguments in the overload

Comment: [edit] your question to add the necessary info.

Comment: Error on which line? Be specific please.